# Proving that the discrete exponential distribution is geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[a] floors the value to a integer.

$$[4.3]=4; [4]=4; [-4.3]=-5$$

Prove that the discrete exponential distribution is geometric distribution.

Research:
I have no idea how to represent the [j] values, where j is exponentialy distributed.
And even I did how do I prove that this random variable is with geometric distribution?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/916879/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Say $E\sim \exp(\lambda)$.
- Then, $\mathbb{P}(E>x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$
- Set $G=\lfloor E \rfloor$, and let $m$ be a nonnegative integer.
- Then, by definition of $G$, we have that $\mathbb{P}(G\ge m)=\mathbb{P}(\lfloor E\rfloor\ge m)$.
- As $m$ is an integer, this is actually equal to $\mathbb{P}(E\ge m)$
- By the second point, this is equal to $e^{-\lambda m}$

So, we have established that $\mathbb{P}(G\ge m)=e^{-\lambda m}$

- Now, as an event, $\{G=m\}$ is the same as $\{G\ge m\}\cap\{G\ge m+1\}^C$
- From this, $\mathbb{P}(G=m)=\mathbb{P}(G\ge m)-\mathbb{P}(G\ge m+1)$
- By our earlier calculations, this is equal to $e^{-\lambda m}-e^{-\lambda (m+1)}=e^{-\lambda m}(1-e^{-\lambda})$

Thus, we obtain that $\mathbb{P}(G=m)=e^{-\lambda m}(1-e^{-\lambda})$.

From this, we can say that $G$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $e^{-\lambda}$.

Comment: What does  P(E>x) represent

Comment: The probability that the random variable $E$ is greater than the value $x$

Comment: and why P(G≥m)=P(⌊E⌋≥m)=P(E≥m)=e−λmP(G≥m)=P(⌊E⌋≥m)=P(E≥m)=e−λm => P(G=m)=P(G≥m)−P(G≥m+1)=e−λm−e−λ(m+1)

Comment: @Harton i've updated my answer to add greater detail ... had you understood any of the answer previously, though? you basically copied out half of the answer in your comment :S