# Probability (Transformation Method)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with CDF: 
$$F_{X}(x)= 1-e^{\lambda x}$$
Let $Y$ be a random variable defined in terms of $X$ as $Y=m$ if $m\leq X < m+1$, where $m$ is a non-negative integer.
Compute the distribution of $Y$.

My idea was to apply $$f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}(h^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy}h^{-1}(y)\right|$$

First I try $f_{X}(x)= \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$
And the funtion $Y=h(X)=m$. But I can do much with this:$$f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}(h^{-1}(?))\left|\frac{d}{dy}h^{-1}(?)\right|$$

Solution: $Y\sim Geom(1-e^{-\lambda})$ $\Rightarrow$ $f_{Y}(y)=(1-e^{-\lambda})e^{-\lambda}$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please see [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ).

Comment: Duplicate of [Variables defined as floor and fraction part from exponentially distributed random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916879/variables-defined-as-floor-and-fraction-part-from-exponentially-distributed-rand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with: You probably wanted to write $F_X(x)= \begin{cases} 1-e^{-\lambda x} & x>0 \\ 0 & x \le 0 \end{cases}$, otherwise it isn't good distribution function

You shouldn't use the method to obtain density of $Y$ simply because $Y$ does not have density at all. Note that $Y$ only takes values from $\mathbb N$ so to find its distribution it is enought to find values $\mathbb P(Y=n)$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$. By definition, for $n \in \mathbb N$ we get: $Y=n$ if and only if $X \in [n,n+1)$. So:

$\mathbb P(Y=n) = \mathbb P(X \in [n,n+1)) = \mathbb P(X < n+1) - \mathbb P(X \le n) = e^{-\lambda n}-e^{-\lambda(n+1)} = e^{-\lambda n}(1-e^{-\lambda})$

Writing $p=(1-e^{-\lambda})$, you get $\mathbb P(Y=n) = (1-p)^n p$, so you should recognize  (one version of) geometric distribution. So that $Y \sim  Geo(1-e^{-\lambda})$