# What is the distribution of Y if Y is the largest integer smaller or equal to x, where x is exponentially distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I think $Y$ is of a discrete distribution since it takes only an integer and I tried to use the cumulative distribution $X$ to find the distribution of $Y$ but it seems not possible.

How should I approach this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you express the set $\{Y = k\}$ in terms of $X$? Perhaps you can take it from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/805796/874549

Comment: Can you tell what approach did you try?

Comment: @MushuNrek thanks for that! My mistake was trying to integrate to infinity

Comment: @noam.szyfer yes! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X \sim Exp(\lambda),$ so that $X$ is distributed according to the pdf
$$f_\lambda(x) = \lambda e^{- \lambda x} \chi_{[0, \infty)}(x)$$
and $Y := \lfloor X \rfloor.$ Then
$$\mathbb{P}(Y = k) = \mathbb{P}(k \leq X < k + 1) = \int_k^{k + 1} f_\lambda(x) dx = e^{- \lambda k} - e^{- \lambda(k + 1)} = e^{- \lambda k}(1 - e^{- \lambda}).$$
I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, I see what I did wrong, I tried to integrate to infinity